# concat string to beginning of another string

Tags: c, string, concatenation

Is there a function that allows me to concatenate a string to the beginning of another string?

For example, if I have

```
str1 = "world!";
str2 = "Hello, ";
```

Is there some way to combine those strings into one string that contains "Hello, world!"?

Comment: Did you had a look at `strcat`?

Answer (score 2):

It can be done in many ways. Here is one approach which uses dynamic memory allocation:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void)
{ 
    char* str1 = "world!";
    char* str2 = "Hello, ";
    char* p = malloc(strlen(str1) + strlen(str2) + 1);  // Allocate memory for the new string
    strcpy(p, str2);  // Copy str2 to the new string
    strcat(p, str1);  // Concatenate str1
    printf("%s", p);  // print it
    free(p);          // free the allocated memory
    return 0;
}
```

Try the code here: http://ideone.com/oydJHN

Instead of dynamic memory allocation you can use something like:

```
#define LENGTH_OF_RESULT 100

char result[LENGTH_OF_RESULT];
```

instead of `char* p;`. You must make sure that LENGTH_OF_RESULT is large enough to hold the concatenated string.

The benefit of dynamic memory allocation is that you don't need to worry about the size of the destination string - just allocate what you need based on the length of the input strings and add 1 for the null-termination.

The downside of using dynamic memory allocation is that you must remember to `free` the memory when done with it.

Comment: You forgot `stdlib.h`

Answer (score 2):

You can do it using statically declared memory as opposed to dynamically allocating the memory as well and avoid the additional call `malloc` and call to `free`. Either way is fine. A simple example is:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

enum { MAXL = 64 }; /* constant for max concatenated length */

int main (void) {

    char str1[MAXL] = "hello";
    char str2[MAXL] = "world";
    char dest[2*MAXL+1] = "";

    strcpy (dest, str1);
    strcat (dest, " ");
    strcat (dest, str2);
    strcat (dest, "!");

    printf ("\n%s\n\n", dest);

    return 0;
}
```

**Example Use**

```
$ ./bin/concat

hello world!
```

The key either way is simply insuring you have adequate space in your `destination` string to hold the concatenated results. Combining 2 - strings at their max character count means with only 1 separator, you can use twice the storage available for the existing strings (you get back one char by only having to use 1 *nul-terminating* character in the combined string instead of 2 before). If you add additional characters as separators, you simply must add those to the total storage available as well. Let me know if you have questions.

Comment: Why not `#define MAXL 64`?

Comment: That works fine too. But I pulled from a file that had the `enum { MAXC = 32, MAXL = 64 };` so I just deleted one and kept the other (laziness `:)`

Answer (score 1):

You can make your own function.It is quite easy:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void my_strcat(char *dst, const char *src);


int main(void)
{
    char dst[50] = "world";
    char src[] = "hello ";
    my_strcat(dst, src);
    printf("%s\n", dst);
    return 0;
}

void my_strcat(char *dst, const char *src)
{
    size_t dst_len = strlen(dst) + 1, src_len = strlen(src);
    memmove(dst + src_len, dst, dst_len);
    memcpy(dst, src, src_len);
}
```

Comment: Your code won't NUL-terminate, right? So, UB...

Comment: it does now.I considered NUL-terminating but declaration like `char dst[50] = "string"` will leave abundant 0's

Comment: Ah, yes. I missed that.